# Python: Different constructor footprint in derived class

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor, abstract-class

How can I have a different constructor in a derived class in Python?

If I try something like this:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractproperty, abstractmethod

class AbstractClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

and

```
import AbstractClass

class DerivedClass(AbstractClass):

    _prop = ''
    def __init__(self, param):
        self._prop = param
```

I get

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I would like to do something like

```
if (cl_param == '1'):
  obj = DerivedClass1('1', 'c')
else if (cl_param == '2'):
  obj = DerivedClass2('2', 'foo', 2)
```

and so on. The rest of the interface would be similar in each class, they just need different initialisation parameters. Or do I have to circumvent this by giving the parameters in a list?

Comment: How are you calling the `DerivedClass` constructor such that it is giving that error?

Comment: Pretty much like I do in the last code snippet (I have only one derived class so far, so I don't have the if-else construct yet). I have self + three parameters, I call it like "obj = DerivedClass('1', '2', '3')".

Comment: You do see that you've defined it to only take a single parameter other than the instance, right?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Object creation works if I change my DerivedClass not to derive from the base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Python tutorial, §4.7.3, "Arbitrary Argument Lists"](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists)

Comment: So inheritance doesn't work like it does in e.g. C++ where you can have multiple constructors with different footprints?

Comment: Python does not support function/method overloading.

Comment: Ah, ok. That I didn't realise.

Answer (score 8):

Ensure you inherit from a class, not a module.

I got the same error message when using django models

The mistake was in inheriting my model from models.Model

I had something like

```
class Entry(models):
    content = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

when it should have been

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Note the missing **models.Model**

Answer (score 3):

```
class DerivedClass(AbstractClass):

    _props = ''
    def __init__(self, *params):
        self._props = params
        print params # (1,2,3,4)

c = DerivedClass(1,2,3,4)
```